# Item Level Permission

Tags: item-level-permissions

I have a list  with its Item-Level Permission is set to;

Read access: = Read Items that were created by the user

Basically what is required is for the list item, only be accessible to the creator/owner until its field "Status" value becomes "Approved", then everybody should be able to have see and read the list item.

I have tried the **Impersonation Step and "Replace [permission of the group] in current item"** starting from "Read" to "Full Access" but members of that group still don't see the list items created by other member.  However, myself and other colleague who's the owner of the List and has Full Access are able to see everyone's list item (entries).

Can anyone point me to the right procedure on how to make it happen?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there an element of 'security'?  By this I mean is it 100% necessary that people don't see items before the Status=Approved ?  If you simply wish to filter out items where the status does not equal Approved, you can create a new view and apply a filter.  Otherwise you will likely need some custom coding OR use a Sharepoint workflow to achieve what you have described.

Comment: Thank you Tally...the only issue with this is its approval process which are Status base, meaning in infopath form, button to Authorized is enabled if Status is "For Authorization" and button to Approve is enabled if Status is "For Approval"...that is how the form is designed...so if I filtered the view, none of the Authorizers and Approvers will see those list items pending action...and if it will be open to all, other users can see those buttons and might press them intentionally or unintentionally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Item-Level Permission" is not part of the SharePoint security model, but rather is a filter implemented as a library feature. This is a special kind of "security" that only works with selected lists and is not managed like the other SharePoint security features. The Impersonation Step impacts security settings and not this filter.

You will need to create a workflow for when users are adding items that sets security permissions to be read only for the user, and Full Control for site owners. When an item is approved another workflow changes the security permissions so all can read.

Comment: Thanks Mike...I took your suggestion and just leave the Item-Level Permission to Read access = **All users**  then setup a work-flow to remove **Contributor** access permission and replaced it with **Read** during the Approval process. The application owner somehow agree and accept this work-around but still prefers the original concept.